# PHP 5.4.45 Call to undefined function mysql_connect() mysql 5.6 error en servidor

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, php5, debian

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de hacer una conexion de prueba a mi base de datos en mysql desde php 5.45 tengo el siguiente codigo

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "user";
$password = "password";
$link = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password);
if (!$link) {
  die('No Se pudo acceder a la BD: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Conexion satisfactoria';
mysql_close($link);
```

y al entrar a compilar mi codigo desde el navegador me genera la salida del error: "**Call to undefined function mysql_connect()**"

estoy usando un servidor de debian 9 y phpbrew para la version de php 5.4.45 mysql 5.6 y openssl 1.0.2o

Comment: ¿Seguro que esa versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Correcto si estoy compilando una version antigua de php

Answer (score 0):

No estas llamando a la base de datos prueba esto

```
    $serverName = "localhost"; 
    $userName = "user"; 
    $password = "password";
    $basededatos="nombrebasededatos"
     $link = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password,$basededatos);
 if (!$link)
 { die('No Se pudo acceder a la BD: ' . mysql_error()); }
 echo 'Conexion satisfactoria'; mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: 2 comentarios: el error no tiene que ver con el hecho de que no ha seleccionado la bd aunque bien por señalar ese detalle, coméntale que tu respuesta se basa en mysqli y no mysql

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo miro mas a detalle tu código tiene un error, si usas `mysqli_connect`, entonces por que accedes al posible error de esta forma: `mysql_close($link);`

Comment: Correcto no esoty usando la funccion de `mysqli_connect()`, si no la funcion de `mysql_connect()` adicional a eso aprovecho para agregar que la funcion de `mysqli_connect()` igualmente genera el error de que no la reconoce como una funcion